# SharedElement and custom EnterTransition causes memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-memory, leakcanary

Having a shared element animation and also a custom enter animation causes the activity to leak.

Any idea what might be the cause?

`09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * com.feeln.android.activity.MovieDetailActivity has leaked:
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * GC ROOT android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.this$0
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.app.ActivityThread.mActivities
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.util.ArrayMap.mArray
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references array java.lang.Object[].[1]
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.feeln.android.activity.MovieDetailActivity.mActivityTransitionState
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.app.ActivityTransitionState.mEnterTransitionCoordinator
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.app.EnterTransitionCoordinator.mEnterViewsTransition
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.transition.TransitionSet.mParent
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.transition.TransitionSet.mListeners
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references java.util.ArrayList.array
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references array java.lang.Object[].[1]
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener$1.val$runningTransitions (anonymous class extends android.transition.Transition$TransitionListenerAdapter)
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.util.ArrayMap.mArray
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references array java.lang.Object[].[2]
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.mContext
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * leaks com.feeln.android.activity.MovieDetailActivity instance
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ [ 09-21 16:19:31.007 28269:31066 D/LeakCanary ]
    * Reference Key: af2b6234-297e-4bab-96e9-02f1c4bca171
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * Device: LGE google Nexus 5 hammerhead
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * Android Version: 5.1.1 API: 22 LeakCanary: 1.3.1
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ * Durations: watch=6785ms, gc=262ms, heap dump=8553ms, analysis=33741ms
09-21 16:19:31.007  28269-31066/com.sample.android D/LeakCanary﹕ [ 09-21 16:19:31.007 28269:31066 D/LeakCanary ]`

To reproduce you need to have a big shared image animation and also a custom EnterAnimation and setEnterSharedElementCallback . All this are from the support library.

Here is how i set the EnterTransition:

```
private SharedElementCallback mCallback = new SharedElementCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedElementStart(List<String> sharedElementNames, List<View> sharedElements, List<View> sharedElementSnapshots) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            if(sharedElements.size()>0)
                getWindow().setEnterTransition(makeEnterTransition(getWindow().getEnterTransition(), getSharedElement(sharedElements)));
        }
    }


    private View getSharedElement(List<View> sharedElements)
    {
        for (final View view : sharedElements)
        {
            if (view instanceof ImageView)
            {
                return view;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 19):

Case of leaks lies in `TransitionManager.sRunningTransitions` where each `DecorView` adds and never removes. `DecorView` has link to his `Activity`'s `Context`. Because of `sRunningTransitions` is static field, it has permanent chain of references to `Activity`, which will never be collected by GC.

I don't known why TransitionManager.sRunningTransitions needs, but if you remove `Activity`'s `DecorView` from it, your problem will be solved. Follow code is example, how do it. In your activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    removeActivityFromTransitionManager(Activity activity);
}

private static void removeActivityFromTransitionManager(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        return;
    }
    Class transitionManagerClass = TransitionManager.class;
    try {
        Field runningTransitionsField = transitionManagerClass.getDeclaredField("sRunningTransitions");
            runningTransitionsField.setAccessible(true);
        //noinspection unchecked
        ThreadLocal<WeakReference<ArrayMap<ViewGroup, ArrayList<Transition>>>> runningTransitions
                = (ThreadLocal<WeakReference<ArrayMap<ViewGroup, ArrayList<Transition>>>>)
                runningTransitionsField.get(transitionManagerClass);
        if (runningTransitions.get() == null || runningTransitions.get().get() == null) {
            return;
        }
        ArrayMap map = runningTransitions.get().get();
        View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        if (map.containsKey(decorView)) {
            map.remove(decorView);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an open issue in the Android framework about this? I'm having the same issue but I couldn't find any mention of this anywhere else.

Comment: @fast3r I don't know about an open issue in the Android framework. If you want, you may do it.

Comment: It works for me. Not sure why this is required. I wonder if I'm doing something wrong. I'm having the same leak on 2 different apps :(

Comment: @fast3r Here's a link to the issue on the tracker. They said it will be fixed in Nougat: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170469

Comment: Possibly the ugliest workaround I have ever found. There is no other way to solve this though :(

Comment: The only thing uglier is that I'm now using this solution AND [fahmy's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37011524/383414) solution to plug the holes, since both fix different issues. Great hack, Delargo - sometimes "ugly" is the way we have to roll.

Comment: No field sRunningTransitions in class Landroid/support/transition/TransitionManager;

Comment: @mladj0ni my solution works with android.transition.TransitionManager class. Try to change imports.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now I am getting this error:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.remove(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener$1.onTransitionEnd

Comment: @mladj0ni What version of android do you use?

Comment: @mladj0ni The solution may do not work with transitions from support library. Check, that you use only built-in transitions.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but it is really not working when you need to deal with orientation changes and shared element transactions. Unfortunately it's crashing the app with a crash mentioned above in the comments....

Comment: I don't think so. As I thought about it, it works as expected since on rotation the activity is destroyed and recreated. I had a base activity where i called your method, so i just removed the base activty from that specific class where i need to have orientation change. Gladly on other screens the orientation is locked to portrait.

Answer (score 6):

The solution by @Delargo did not work for me. However, I stumbled upon [this solution](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190196#c3) on Android issue tracker that did finally work for me.

The idea is to use the following class (aptly named `LeakFreeSupportSharedElementCallback`, subclassed from the `SharedElementCallback`) in activities that are using the activity transitions. Just copy the entire class to your project.

1. [LeakFreeSupportSharedElementCallback](https://gist.github.com/fesago90/ae7a56628c35e65ddaab)

You'll also need the static methods `createDrawableBitmap(Drawable)` and `createViewBitmap(View, Matrix, RectF)` from the following class. These are used by the `LeakFreeSupportSharedElementCallback` class.

2. [TransitionUtils](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/transition/TransitionUtils.java)

After you've got the the `LeakFreeSupportSharedElementCallback` class setup add the following to the activities that uses activity transition framework:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        setEnterSharedElementCallback(new LeakFreeSupportSharedElementCallback());
        setExitSharedElementCallback(new LeakFreeSupportSharedElementCallback());
}
```

With that memory was being freed up by GC after the transition animations.

Comment: Each solution seems to fix a different leak, so I now have this code, and the [workaround by Delargo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34542473/383414) in my app. Garbage collector is working correctly now.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier it still produces OOM

Answer (score 0):

Sergei Vasilenko's solution in tandem with fahmy's seems to work the best for me, but the former does introduce the crash Mladen Rakonjac mentioned:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.remove(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
android.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener$1.onTransitionEnd (TransitionManager.java:306)
```

This happens because under the hood there's a `TransitionListener` in the `TransitionManager` that tries to access the list of running transitions by using the DecorView as key. But since the hack removes the DecorView and some part of this transition process is asynchronous, plus that the listener is not expecting null answers, sometimes it will result in a crash here:

```
mTransition.addListener(new TransitionListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
        ArrayList<Transition> currentTransitions =
                   runningTransitions.get(mSceneRoot); //"mSceneRoot" is basically the DecorView
            currentTransitions.remove(transition); //This line crashes, because "currentTransitions" is null
            transition.removeListener(this);
        }
    });
```

To fix that, I made the following changes to the workaround:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.removeActivityFromTransitionManager() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        return;
    }
    val transitionManagerClass: Class<*> = TransitionManager::class.java
    try {
        val runningTransitionsField: Field =
            transitionManagerClass.getDeclaredField("sRunningTransitions")
        runningTransitionsField.isAccessible = true
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val runningTransitions: ThreadLocal<WeakReference<ArrayMap<ViewGroup, ArrayList<Transition>>>?> =
            runningTransitionsField.get(transitionManagerClass) as ThreadLocal<WeakReference<ArrayMap<ViewGroup, ArrayList<Transition>>>?>
        if (runningTransitions.get() == null || runningTransitions.get()?.get() == null) {
            return
        }
        val map: ArrayMap<ViewGroup, ArrayList<Transition>> =
            runningTransitions.get()?.get() as ArrayMap<ViewGroup, ArrayList<Transition>>
        map[window.decorView]?.let { transitionList ->
            transitionList.forEach { transition ->
                //Add a listener to all transitions. The last one to finish will remove the decor view:
                transition.addListener(object : Transition.TransitionListener {
                    override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {
                        //When a transition is finished, it gets removed from the transition list
                        // internally right before this callback. Remove the decor view only when
                        // all the transitions related to it are done:
                        if (transitionList.isEmpty()) {
                            map.remove(window.decorView)
                        }
                        transition.removeListener(this)
                    }

                    override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: Transition?) {}
                    override fun onTransitionPause(transition: Transition?) {}
                    override fun onTransitionResume(transition: Transition?) {}
                    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition?) {}
                })
            }
            //If there are no active transitions, just remove the decor view immediately:
            if (transitionList.isEmpty()) {
                map.remove(window.decorView)
            }
        }
    } catch (_: Throwable) {}
}
```

So basically my fix is does the following:

1. Check if there are transitions running related to the DecorView. If no, then remove the DecorView immediately.
2. If yes, add a `TransitionListener` to all the transitions related to the DecorView. When each transition ends, these listeners check if they were the last transition to finish, and if yes, they will remove the DecorView.
   This approach makes the DecorView available to racing transitions, but makes sure that at the end it will get removed.

Now, I did not confirm if this solves the crash related to orientation changes, but I'm cautiously optimistic that it does.