# Memory leak using Lollipop's transitions

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-transitions

I'm trying to implement transition between fragment (that attached to the MainActivity) with RecyclerView and the DetailActivity.

In my fragment, I've added RecyclerView listener in *onStart()* method:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mRecyclerItemClickListener = new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), (view, position) -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ConstantsManager.POSITION_ID_KEY, mFilmsAdapter.getImdbIdByPosition(position));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat
                        .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity());
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(), intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());
            } else {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(mRecyclerItemClickListener);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mTopFilmsPresenter.attachView(this);
        mTopFilmsPresenter.getFilms();
    }
```

You can see, that the transition begins in the if block. In the DetailActivity I have the following method which I call in *onCreate()*:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void setupWindowAnimations() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Explode explode = new Explode();
            explode.setDuration(ConstantsManager.TRANSITION_DURATION);
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(explode);
            getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);
        }
    }
```

And in the MainActivity I have almost a similar method, which I also call in *onCreate()*:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void setWindowAnimations() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Explode explode = new Explode();
            explode.setDuration(ConstantsManager.TRANSITION_DURATION);
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(explode);
            getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);
            getWindow().setReenterTransition(explode);
            getWindow().setReturnTransition(explode);
        }
    }
```

I've also implemented **Transition.TransitionListener** interface in the DetailActivity, because documentation says:
*A transition listener receives notifications from a transition. Notifications indicate transition lifecycle events.*

So I'm trying to remove listener in the **onTransitionEnd(Transition transition), onTransitionCancel(Transition transition)** and **onTransitionPause(Transition transition)** callbacks:

```
    @Override
    public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
        transition.removeListener(this);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {
        transition.removeListener(this);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {
        transition.removeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

    }
```

I'm using [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) for memory leaks detections and it detects a memory leak after transition:

[image]
[image]

So I am wondering how can I remove transition listener(s) to prevent this memory leak?

Comment: I have the exact same problem (detected with LeakCanary also). Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34542473/4034572) from a question that's exactly the same issue. It works for me.

Comment: @AlbertVila sorry for the long respond. You're absolutely right. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SharedElement and custom EnterTransition causes memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698049/sharedelement-and-custom-entertransition-causes-memory-leak)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Albert Vila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4034572/albert-vila) for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791795/memory-leak-using-lollipops-transitions/36594404#comment60165928_35791795). The problem lies in `TransitionManager.sRunningTransitions` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698049/sharedelement-and-custom-entertransition-causes-memory-leak/34542473#34542473) topic.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you release the `Activity` reference since you are strongly holding onto it within the `Transition` class. A simple `Transition.removeListener(this)` (since your activity implements the interface) in it's `onDestroy()` method should prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Also it appears you left out the code where you register this `Transition`